# Basic Regular Expression Meaning?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this regex:

```
'/^ANSWER\:(.+?)$/'
```

I know this roughly translates as:

Strings that begin with "ANSWER:" and...

I'm not exactly sure what the

```
(.+?)$
```

translates to? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

```
(       # begin capturing group
  .+?     # match any character (.) one or more times (+) as few times as possible (?)
)       # end capturing group
$       # end of string anchor (or end of line anchor, if multiline option is enabled)
```

The following link has a nice summary of regex syntax:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: What is the different between `.+?` and `.+`?

Comment: @invisal with question mark `as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)` without `as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)`

Comment: `.+` is greedy (matches as many characters as possible), `.+?` is lazy (matches as few characters as possible).  So for the string `"red blue"`, `.+e` would match the entire string but `.+?e` would just match `"re"`.

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesized section of the regular expression corresponds to a *capturing group*, or a part of the regular expression that can be referred to later, so that you can get whatever text fit the sub-regular expression inside the capturing group. The `.` means to match a single character, and `+` means at least one instance of, so `.+` can be thought of as "at least one of any character." However, the `+` by itself is "greedy," meaning it matches as many characters as possible, whereas when followed by `?`, it is instructed to match "lazily," or as few characters as possible. Because the regular expression ends with `$`, I think that the `?` wouldn't change how the regular expression matched strings, as any match would be forced to match all characters until the end of the line anyways.

Comment: Quite right.  Many regex users--even some very experienced ones--seem to regard reluctant quantifiers as a kind of magical ward that prevents all manner of problems, so they use them indiscriminately.  They usually get away with it, too.